# What is the delimiter of fgets()?

Tags: c++, fgets

When i execute fgets() function to following file:

**code.txt**

```
this is a test
foobar
all your base
```

it also copies '**\n**'.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the `fgets` function before posting this? If you're on a *nix type system type `man fgets`. If not, google `man fgets` instead.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Hey but why downvotes. I think its not wrong question.

Comment: @pranitkothari questions where it's clear the asker has not put forth any effort (beyond the effort required to post the question) tend to get downvoted. In this case, the documentation for `fgets` is very simple to understand, and any question fitting the pattern "how does function X work" should be preceded by a reading of function X's documentation.

Comment: @pranitkothari _'I think its not wrong question.'_ but not a very good one either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design:

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a  is read **and transferred to s**, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. (emphasis is mine)

If you would prefer to not get `\n`, use `fscanf("%100s", str)` (put the actual size instead of 100).

In C++, use `std::string` and `std::getline` for a much more flexible way of reading lines from a file.

Comment: lets say maximum number of character to be read is 1000.
now if we execute fgets on code.txt then it will read only first line but not whole file which is less than 1000 bytes.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghVirdi `fgets` reads the line, not the whole file. If you want to read the whole file, use [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fread.html).

Comment: @HarmeetSinghVirdi Absolutely. If you do not want to see `'\n'`s in the buffer, replace them all with whatever the character that you want to see there instead.